# Can we make a worse automatic card shuffling machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, playing-cards

So I've been droodling on a blackjack project, and one of the issues we need to solve is how to shuffle the cards. I've implemented a method that simulates hand shuffling (E.g split the shoe (either 2, 4, 6, 8 decks) into two heaps, and then merge a handful of cards together alternating between overhand and riffle shuffles.

However, I wanted to also implement a **card shuffling machine (csm) design**, *which as closely as possible, imitates a real one*. This means cards are removed from the machine, and that is has a "real life" form of internal design. E.g how it shuffles the cards.

My first attempt was an "*evil*" design. A machine that would be impossible to count against.

```
@dataclass
class CsmEvil:

    __cards: list[Card] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):
        random.shuffle(self.__cards)

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.__cards.append(card)

    def add_cards(self, cards):
        self.__cards.extend(cards)

    @property
    def next_card(self):
        if not self.__cards:
            return None
        random.shuffle(self.__cards)
        return self.__cards.pop()
```

But, again it is not very realistic that the machines shuffles on every drawn card. So this leads to the question: **How do we make a worse card shuffling machine?**

My next idea was a *wheel design*. This would rotate and insert or remove cards, and mimic a linked list. I took inspiration from here https://youtu.be/qx3UUOH6TR8, however the design in the video is not quite right as it is meant for single decks. It looks something like this

[image]

Now, the real card shuffling machines looks like this

[image]

Which is different from the ones we buy privately.
My guess was that the snail house contains a circular "wheel" as in the first picture, but it goes all the way round. ***This is just a guess as how the machine depicted above works**

```
Spoke = Annotated[
    Optional[Card], "A position in a 'wheel' that either contains a card or None"
]
Wheel = Annotated[list[Spoke], "A list of spokes"]


@dataclass
class CsmWheel:

    """A continuous shuffling machine (csm) based on a wheel design

    Asume our wheel has 4 positions (or spokes), a card may occopy
    any of these four spots. When we add or remove cards we rotate
    the wheel semi-randomly and insert or remove cards, while keeping
    check on the number of available spokes.

    Before adding any cards we rotate the wheel a random number of spokes.
    A wheel design is equivalent to a linked list

                      POS 0

                    0 0 0 0 0
                0 0 0   0   0 0 0
                0       0       0
              0 0       0       0 0
              0         0         0
        POS 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 POS 1
              0         0         0
              0 0       0       0 0
                0       0       0
                0 0 0   0   0 0 0
                    0 0 0 0 0

                      POS 2

    Attributes:
        card_limit: The maximum number of cards the CsmWheel can hold
                    Equivalent to the number of spokes
    """

    card_limit: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.__wheel: Wheel = [None for _ in range(self.card_limit)]
        self.available = self.card_limit
        self.wheel_pos = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"CsmWheel(cards={self.cards}, available={self.available}, limit={self.card_limit})"

    @property
    def rotation(self) -> int:
        return random.randint(0, self.card_limit)

    @property
    def cards(self) -> int:
        return self.card_limit - self.available

    @property
    def next_card(self) -> Spoke:

        if self.available >= self.card_limit:
            return None

        for position, spoke in self.spin_wheel(self.rotation):
            if spoke is None:
                continue
            self.__wheel[position] = None
            self.available += 1
            return spoke

    def spin_wheel(self, rotation: int = 0) -> Generator[Tuple[int, Spoke], None, None]:
        if rotation:
            self.wheel_pos += rotation
            self.wheel_pos %= self.card_limit
        while True:
            self.wheel_pos += 1
            if self.wheel_pos >= self.card_limit:
                self.wheel_pos = 0

            yield self.wheel_pos, self.__wheel[self.wheel_pos]

    def insert_card_now(self) -> bool:
        return random.random() < 1 / self.available

    def add_card(self, card: Card) -> None:
        self.add_cards([card])

    def add_cards(self, cards: list[Card]) -> None:
    
        if not (cardz := cards.copy()):
            return

        if self.available < len(cards):
            raise ValueError("CSM is full!")

        for position, spoke in self.spin_wheel(self.rotation):
            if spoke is not None or not self.insert_card_now():
                continue

            self.__wheel[position] = cardz.pop()
            self.available -= 1

            if not cardz:
                return
```

This can be used as follows

```
csm = CsmWheel(
    card_limit=len(deck) * 8,
)

print(csm)
for i in range(8):
    csm.add_cards(deck.cards)
print(csm)
print(csm.next_card)
```

Assuming of course that `deck` exists.

This is *slightly* worse than `random.shuffle` as it is not a completely random insertion. Basically it spins around and attempts to insert chances with a probability of how many cards remain `random.random() < 1 / self.available`. **From my tests it is only, very slightly less random than the `shuffle`**. Which, again leads us back to the title: *can we make a more realistic automatic card shuffling machine*?

A second reason why my design is not perfect is that to insert a deck of cards into the spokes, it spins about 20 000 times. Again far from realistic.. I would imagine the sheer horror of the casino personnel if my machine was implemented and it started spinning at a several thousand rounds per minute.

- Is my method solid? I *know* it is not fast, nor does it need to be. Usually cards are collected in a discard tray, so this code would only run when there are X cards in the discard tray. I just need it to be "real".
- Is there a better way to accurately imitate how a card shuffling machine works?

For instance the common snail design: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSnDHv-AQQ8. Appears to have some sort of wheel (the snail house), a buffer (loading tray), but also a part where cards just lie readily available for the dealer to pick. My design misses the last part.

However, I seriously do not believe a shuffling machine would shuffle all 8 decks perfectly as a Python program would, so there needs to be some trickery going on.. Maybe it uses a wheel design, and then spits out X cards into the tray and keeps the rest inside the wheel? I am struggling to land on a proper design..

## Full code

```
import random
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Annotated, Generator, Optional, Tuple


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Card:
    rank: str
    values: list[int]
    suit: str

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.rank}{self.suit if self.suit is not None else ''}"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.rank.capitalize()}{self.suit}"


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Deck:
    cards: list[Card]
    name: str = ""

    def __len__(self):
        return len(cards)


RANKS = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
SUITS = ["♣", "♢", "♡", "♠"]
VALUES = [[1, 13], 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

cards = []
for i, rank in enumerate(RANKS):
    value = [v] if isinstance(v := VALUES[i], int) else v
    for suit in SUITS:
        cards.append(Card(rank=rank, suit=suit, values=value))

STANDARD_52_DECK = Deck(cards)


@dataclass
class CsmEvil:

    __cards: list[Card] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):
        random.shuffle(self.__cards)

    def add_card(self, card):
        self.__cards.append(card)

    def add_cards(self, cards):
        self.__cards.extend(cards)

    @property
    def next_card(self):
        if not self.__cards:
            return None
        random.shuffle(self.__cards)
        return self.__cards.pop()


Spoke = Annotated[
    Optional[Card], "A position in a 'wheel' that either contains a card or None"
]
Wheel = Annotated[list[Spoke], "A list of spokes"]


@dataclass
class CsmWheel:

    """A continuous shuffling machine (csm) based on a wheel design

    Asume our wheel has 4 positions (or spokes), a card may occopy
    any of these four spots. When we add or remove cards we rotate
    the wheel semi-randomly and insert or remove cards, while keeping
    check on the number of available spokes.

    Before adding any cards we rotate the wheel a random number of spokes.
    A wheel design is equivalent to a linked list

                      POS 0

                    0 0 0 0 0
                0 0 0   0   0 0 0
                0       0       0
              0 0       0       0 0
              0         0         0
        POS 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 POS 1
              0         0         0
              0 0       0       0 0
                0       0       0
                0 0 0   0   0 0 0
                    0 0 0 0 0

                      POS 2

    Attributes:
        card_limit: The maximum number of cards the CsmWheel can hold
                    Equivalent to the number of spokes
    """

    card_limit: int
    insertion_chance: float = 0.5

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.__wheel: Wheel = [None for _ in range(self.card_limit)]
        self.available = self.card_limit
        self.wheel_pos = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"CsmWheel(cards={self.cards}, available={self.available}, limit={self.card_limit})"

    @property
    def rotation(self) -> int:
        return random.randint(0, self.card_limit)

    @property
    def cards(self) -> int:
        return self.card_limit - self.available

    @property
    def next_card(self) -> Spoke:

        if self.available >= self.card_limit:
            return None

        for position, spoke in self.spin_wheel(self.rotation):
            if spoke is None:
                continue
            self.__wheel[position] = None
            self.available += 1
            return spoke

    def spin_wheel(self, rotation: int = 0) -> Generator[Tuple[int, Spoke], None, None]:
        if rotation:
            self.wheel_pos += rotation
            self.wheel_pos %= self.card_limit
        while True:
            self.wheel_pos += 1
            if self.wheel_pos >= self.card_limit:
                self.wheel_pos = 0

            yield self.wheel_pos, self.__wheel[self.wheel_pos]

    def insert_card_now(self) -> bool:
        return random.random() < 1 / self.available

    def add_card(self, card: Card) -> None:
        self.add_cards([card])

    def add_cards(self, cards: list[Card]) -> None:
    
        if not (cardz := cards.copy()):
            return

        if self.available < len(cards):
            raise ValueError("CSM is full!")

        for position, spoke in self.spin_wheel(self.rotation):
            if spoke is not None or not self.insert_card_now():
                continue

            self.__wheel[position] = cardz.pop()
            self.available -= 1

            if not cardz:
                return


if __name__ == "__main__":

    deck = STANDARD_52_DECK

    csm = CsmWheel(
        card_limit=len(deck) * 8,
    )

    print(csm)
    for i in range(8):
        csm.add_cards(deck.cards)
    print(csm)

    csm.next_card
```

Comment: Well, when you are at it, why not simulate a real one, sticky cards and whatnot :)

Comment: I don't know if it's a term I'm unfamiliar with or just an ordinary typo, but I suspect you mean [Spoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoke) rather than Spook -- although Spooks sound more exciting and are probably capable of achieving a higher level of randomness than that capable from mere mortals.

Comment: @FMc You spooked me with that comment, I guess I spoke too quickly.. Not being a native speaker really shines through does it

Comment: I started reviewing this code, but then I got confused. I assumed from the wheel/spoke metaphor that CsmWheel is an attempt to mimic a shelf shuffler, where the cards (eg 52 of them) are randomly placed on shelves/spokes, and where the number of shelves is considerably smaller than the number of cards (eg, 5 shelves). But your CsmWheel has a shelf for every card. Perhaps you can edit your question to clarify what kind of machine you are trying to mimic. Also, if there is a shelf-per-card, how is your implementation different than `random.shuffle(cards)`?

Comment: @FMc I updated and explained as best I could